# How do you do AWS Lambda function with Function URL Authentication with postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function that I've been working on and testing with Postman using an HTTP function URL.
Now I have applied the Function URL Auth Type "AWS_IAM".

I've created a user with "Access key - Programmatic access" and the AWSLambdaRole which in the permissions json, applies Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction".
I have the access key and secret key for this user.

In postman I have selected "AWS Signature" for auth type, and I have entered the access key and secret key.  I've also entered my AWS Region.  However, I don't know what to enter for "Service Name". The only examples I can find are for accessing APIs created with API Gateway, so the service name indicated is "execute-api".  I'm guessing that is not correct for hitting a lambda Function URL.  Either that, or I'm doing something else wrong.

the response is always: {"Message":"Forbidden"}

What should the service name be for accessing a Lambda Function URl with AWS_IAM Auth Type?

I've spent a lot of time searching and can't find an example demonstrating this.

Comment: The IAM user would need `lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl` permission.

Comment: OMG that was it!  It's working now.  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.  I just created a policy with the action you mentioned and applied it to my user.  Once the permission was there the response told me what the service name should be "lambda".   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IAM permission required to invoke a Lambda function in AWS is:

```
Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
Resource: <ARN of Lambda function>
```

But IAM permission to invoke a Lambda function URL is different. It's:

```
Action: "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl"
Resource: <ARN of Lambda function>
```

You would give these permissions to an IAM principal when using the AWS_IAM auth type for function URLs. See [Security and auth model for Lambda function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I needed.   I created a policy with the action you mentioned and applied it to my user. Once the permission was there, the response in Postman told me what the service name should be "lambda".   With that in place, it's working!